# Form Submission in Headless Python Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have `python` `Selenium` code that can successfully fill and submit forms. I've generally done this through the `.send_keys()` method. I can also successfully click buttons in the form, so no worries there.

In this specific problem:

1. Selenium chromedriver successfully navigates to a search page. The page loads fully.
2. The selenium driver clicks the button to activate all search fields (there are several). The active buttons change from "Search" to "Go", so the page state is verifiably updated in the driver.
3. The selenium driver successfully selects the fields to update, clears, and sends keys. A verification of the page directly thereafter shows that the field values have updated correctly.
4. The selenium driver successfully clicks the "Go" button, as seen by the buttons changing back to "Search"
5. No search results appear. Verification of the form fields show they have all been cleared. A search of the entire outerHTML of the entire driver page shows no search terms. Under normal circumstances, these would be displayed in the old form fields.

e.g. if the element I am changing is this:

```
<input type="text" name="search_field" value="">
```

I can select it and send keys:

```
active_link = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name='search_field']")
active_link.clear()
active_link.send_keys("Jim Beam")
active_link.send_keys(Keys.TAB) # to step off the field, just in case
```

I verify the status of the HTML element has changed:

```
print('Element now set to', active_link.get_attribute('value'))
```

and it displays "Jim Beam".

I can do exactly the same activity on the search page manually in a chrome browser, and the outcome is that results are displayed. I verify once the Headless Selenium driver clicks the "Go" button and get the driver.page_source and query:

```
"Jim Beam" in driver.page_source
```

Which returns False. In the expected result, it should return True. This should not be a wait time issue, as I manually test this by waiting for a number of seconds... and re-test, and re-test...
Additionally, since the search buttons update instantly, I am a bit perplexed as to why this behaviour is so unexpected. I have also tried performing this same action through a .submit() method - this does not raise an error but also does not change the page state.

I think I have been pretty methodical and I wonder what I am missing.

Comment: It might blocking the headless browser. Is it possible to add web url in your post?

Comment: Sadly it's not accessible.

Comment: Just capture screenshot and check what is displayed on the page?

Comment: Sorry, as it's headless there's not actually anything displayed on the page.